# How to use same key for multiple widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a backdrop widget with a key, the backdrop widget has a gesture when drag down it will close, the problem when i open it in another widget, it cannot closed and trhowing error `Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree.`

i call key from all page that use the backdrop with this

```
final backdropKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'Backdrop');
```

how to fix this problem?

Comment: you can't use the same key for multiple widgets

Comment: so how can i use this ? final RenderBox renderBox = backdropKey.currentContext.findRenderObject();

when i access from other widget?

Comment: Add more context to your question , I mean add some code that we can reproduce your error.

Comment: let say i have widget1 with key final backdropKey = GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'backdrop');
then when i open widgetX i used the sameGlobalKey(debugLabel: 'backdrop'); to make gesture work for draging down to close,
then i have widget2,also to open widgetX, that i have to use GlobalKey(debugLabel: 'backdrop'); for dragging down work

Comment: I/flutter ( 1198): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY GESTURE ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter ( 1198): The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter ( 1198): The method 'findRenderObject' was called on null.
I/flutter ( 1198): Receiver: null
I/flutter ( 1198): Tried calling: findRenderObject()

Answer (score 0):

Keys must be unique amongst the `Elements` with the same parent.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/foundation/Key-class.html

Comment: so how can i use this ? final RenderBox renderBox = backdropKey.currentContext.findRenderObject(); when i access from other widget?

Comment: Can you explain more? and share your code in the question ?

Comment: It's better to write this as comment, otherwise include the necessary part from the link in your answer.